# Javascript array is not accessible as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, twitter

I'm working with the twitter API and I'm hitting a really confusing issue.

I have the following script:

```
const Twitter = require('twitter-api-stream')
const twitterCredentials = require('./credentials').twitter

const twitterApi = new Twitter(twitterCredentials.consumerKey, twitterCredentials.consumerSecret, function(){
    console.log(arguments)
})

twitterApi.getUsersTweets('everycolorbot', 1, twitterCredentials.accessToken, twitterCredentials.accessTokenSecret, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
    if (result) {
        console.log(result) // outputs an array of json objects
        console.log(result.length) //outputs 3506 for some reason (it's only an array of 1)
        console.log(result[0]) // outputs a opening bracket ('[')
        console.log(result[0].text) // outputs undefined
    }
})
```

Which is calling the following function to interact with twitter:

```
TwitterApi.prototype.getUsersTweets = function (screenName, statusCount, userAccessToken, userRefreshToken,cb ) {
    var count = statusCount || 10;
    var screenName = screenName || "";

    _oauth.get(
        "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=" + count + "&screen_name=" + screenName
        , userAccessToken
        , userRefreshToken
        , cb
    );
};
```

It *seems* like I'm getting the result I want. When I log the result itself I get the following output:

```
[
  {
    "created_at": "Thu Sep 01 13:31:23 +0000 2016",
    "id": 771339671632838656,
    "id_str": "771339671632838656",
    "text": "0xe07732",
    "truncated": false,
    ...
  }
]
```

Which is great, an array of the tweets limited to 1 tweet.

The problem I'm running into is when I try to access this array.

```
console.log(result.length) //outputs 3506 for some reason (it's only an array of 1)
console.log(result[0]) // outputs a opening bracket ('[')
console.log(result[0].text) // outputs undefined
```

I read back through the [api docs for the user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) but unless I'm completely missing it I'm not seeing any mention of special output.

Any ideas?

## Update

Thanks @nicematt for pointing out that answer.

Just to elaborate on the solution, I updated my code to this and now I'm getting the result I want:

```
if (result) {
    let tweet = JSON.parse(result)[0] // parses the json and returns the first index
    console.log(tweet.text) // outputs '0xe07732'
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: ```JSON.parse(results)```

Comment: It seems that `result` is a string, maybe a JSON string?

Comment: Yep, that's probably why the length returns 3506.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Result is a `String` and you're indexing it (`result[0]` (whereas `0` is converted to a string), is almost identical to `result.charAt(0)` though), this is why `result[0]` is equal to `"["`–because it's the first character specified in. You forgot to parse the result as JSON data.

```
JSON.parse(result).length // probably 1
```

And `result.text` is `undefined` since `result` (a string) is like an `Object` (but isn't instanceof) and allow lookups and getters to happen in itself.

I'd show the difference between `str[0]` and `str.charAt(0)`, too:

```
str[0] // same as str['0'], but a getter. 0 converts to
       // string (because every key of an object
       // is string in ECMAScript)

str.charAt(0) // get/lookup String#charAt, call it
              // without new `this` context and with arguments list: 0
```

Comment: This is one of the first terminal-only tools I've written. I'm used to seeing that string come across in the browser's console and seeing that it's a string. Thanks for pointing that out. I'm adding that in my 'keep-in-mind' list :)